# How to shift a highchart series to start at 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a chart I have been developing I want both of my series to start at 0. Currently, the series titled "revenue" starts at zero however the one titled "cost" starts at whatever the first calculation is. Is this an error in my push equation or is there a way to shift the series "cost" over one tick so that they both start at zero? This should help you see my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nlem33/L5cY6/11/

```
newdata.push(((++j * ++j) / 2) * selected * units);
```

Comment: I think you should write `j++`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/L5cY6/15/

Comment: What line did you make the changes at? Was it just console.log?